# controlling a marker's info window

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

Does anyone have ideas of how to style the info window's text and background.  They're the lollipops that show when you touch on a pin?

Also, I'm looking for a creative way to programmatically force the info window to display.  Any suggestions?

Thanks...

p.s. Yay!  It's here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GMSMapView.h`'s `GMSMapViewDelegate`:

```
/**
* Called when a marker is about to become selected, and provides an optional
* custom info window to use for that marker if this method returns a UIView.
* If you change this view after this method is called, those changes will not
* necessarily be reflected in the rendered version.
*
* The returned UIView must not have bounds greater than 500 points on either
* dimension.  As there is only one info window shown at any time, the returned
* view may be reused between other info windows.
*
* @return The custom info window for the specified marker, or nil for default
*/
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(id<GMSMarker>)marker;
```

Comment: no problem. i was doing infoWindow work and it's taking me a while too. also, to show info window: `self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker;`. it's all in `GMSMapView.h`

Comment: hello i add 1) @interface MapsViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate> and 2) mapView_.delegate = self;  but my markerInfoWindow not calling is there any solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google's documentation doesn't make the answer to this obvious so expanding on @s12chung's guidance above, here's how to make the info window visibly programatically (for anyone else who's trying to do this)

```
GMSMarkerOptions *pin = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
self.mapView.selectedMarker = [self.mapView addMarkerWithOptions:pin];
```